# Pairs with sum and product formed by the same digits but arranged differently

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all pairs of natural numbers that have the sum and product formed by the same digits but arranged differently.

I can't find the method to begin to solve it. A first example is obviously (9,9)

Comment: your example doesn't work

Comment: @dREaM (9,9) is a pair of natural numbers

Comment: oh ok, gotcha .

Comment: 47,2 is another pair.

Comment: clearly one of the numbers must be  20 or smaller.

Comment: so you just have to solve $za$ is a permutation of $a+z$ for each value of $z$ between $1$ and $20$.

Comment: And for $z\gt10$ we must have $a\lt10z/(z-10)$, so that's an easy finite test -- the only interesting cases are $z\lt10$.

Comment: I'm pretty confident we can find various infinite families.

Answer (score 2):

$\{\text{(2,102584)},\text{(2,105284)},\text{(2,108254)},\text{(2,108740)}
   ,\text{(2,124085)},\text{(2,124256)},\text{(2,125084)},\text{(2,125579
   )},\text{(2,125804)},\text{(2,12584)},\text{(2,125984)},\text{(2,12805
   4)},\text{(2,129584)},\text{(2,140870)},\text{(2,142085)},\text{(2,142
   256)},\text{(2,153758)},\text{(2,175358)},\text{(2,2)},\text{(2,214085
   )},\text{(2,214256)},\text{(2,241085)},\text{(2,241256)},\text{(2,2508
   14)},\text{(2,251084)},\text{(2,258014)},\text{(2,258104)},\text{(2,25
   814)},\text{(2,259814)},\text{(2,260003)},\text{(2,26003)},\text{(2,26
   03)},\text{(2,263)},\text{(2,266033)},\text{(2,266303)},\text{(2,26633
   )},\text{(2,269633)},\text{(2,280514)},\text{(2,281054)},\text{(2,2958
   14)},\text{(2,296003)},\text{(2,29603)},\text{(2,2963)},\text{(2,29663
   3)},\text{(2,299603)},\text{(2,29963)},\text{(2,299963)},\text{(2,3004
   67)},\text{(2,302663)},\text{(2,30467)},\text{(2,304697)},\text{(2,304
   967)},\text{(2,326603)},\text{(2,32663)},\text{(2,326963)},\text{(2,32
   9663)},\text{(2,334667)},\text{(2,3467)},\text{(2,34697)},\text{(2,346
   997)},\text{(2,34967)},\text{(2,349697)},\text{(2,349967)},\text{(2,35
   1758)},\text{(2,357869)},\text{(2,358769)},\text{(2,367508)},\text{(2,
   375158)},\text{(2,375869)},\text{(2,376508)},\text{(2,378569)},\text{(2,385769)},\text{(2,387569)},\text{(2,408710)},\text{(2,410870)},\text
   {(2,412085)},\text{(2,412256)},\text{(2,421085)},\text{(2,421256)},\text{(2,47)},\text{(2,497)},\text{(2,4997)},\text{(2,49997)},\text{(2,49
   9997)},\text{(3,100050)},\text{(3,100338)},\text{(3,10050)},\text{(3,1
   00500)},\text{(3,101337)},\text{(3,10338)},\text{(3,103524)},\text{(3,
   104280)},\text{(3,1050)},\text{(3,10500)},\text{(3,105000)},\text{(3,105234)},\text{(3,107250)},\text{(3,11337)},\text{(3,113739)},\text{(3,
   123504)},\text{(3,123738)},\text{(3,125034)},\text{(3,125070)},\text{(
   3,128040)},\text{(3,134277)},\text{(3,135051)},\text{(3,137931)},\text
   {(3,138462)},\text{(3,138561)},\text{(3,140469)},\text{(3,142467)},\text{(3,143709)},\text{(3,143862)},\text{(3,145050)},\text{(3,14739)},\text{(3,149739)},\text{(3,150351)},\text{(3,150450)},\text{(3,153861)},
   \text{(3,189573)},\text{(3,195873)},\text{(3,206709)},\text{(3,206862)
   },\text{(3,235104)},\text{(3,24)},\text{(3,240468)},\text{(3,241467)},
   \text{(3,243708)},\text{(3,24738)},\text{(3,247524)},\text{(3,248766)}
   ,\text{(3,248964)},\text{(3,249738)},\text{(3,250710)},\text{(3,251034
   )},\text{(3,251070)},\text{(3,252474)},\text{(3,264876)},\text{(3,2648
   94)},\text{(3,274893)},\text{(3,275838)},\text{(3,280410)},\text{(3,28
   1040)},\text{(3,285738)},\text{(3,287493)},\text{(3,306789)},\text{(3,
   307689)},\text{(3,313791)},\text{(5,100250)},\text{(5,102050)},\text{(
   5,10250)},\text{(5,102500)},\text{(5,102590)},\text{(5,105020)},\text{
   (5,106352)},\text{(5,120563)},\text{(5,125603)},\text{(5,12563)},\text
   {(5,125963)},\text{(5,135062)},\text{(5,150002)},\text{(5,15002)},\text{(5,1502)},\text{(5,150632)},\text{(5,153062)},\text{(5,159002)},\text{(5,15902)},\text{(5,159902)},\text{(5,160253)},\text{(5,160523)},\text{(5,162053)},\text{(5,16253)},\text{(5,162593)},\text{(5,165203)},\text{(5,16523)},\text{(5,165923)},\text{(5,190250)},\text{(5,192563)},\text{(5,195002)},\text{(5,19502)},\text{(5,195902)},\text{(5,196253)},
   \text{(5,196523)},\text{(5,199502)},\text{(6,100020)},\text{(6,10020)}
   ,\text{(6,100200)},\text{(6,1020)},\text{(6,10200)},\text{(6,102000)},
   \text{(6,102540)},\text{(6,118641)},\text{(6,120270)},\text{(6,124752)
   },\text{(6,127020)},\text{(6,134022)},\text{(6,136272)},\text{(6,13785
   6)},\text{(6,138621)},\text{(6,142869)},\text{(6,143859)},\text{(6,148
   584)},\text{(6,152085)},\text{(6,158403)},\text{(6,160185)},\text{(8,1
   01480)},\text{(8,106277)},\text{(8,106520)},\text{(8,108752)},\text{(8
   ,113954)},\text{(9,100089)},\text{(9,100350)},\text{(9,10089)},\text{(9,100989)},\text{(9,101250)},\text{(9,10350)},\text{(9,103500)},\text{
   (9,105750)},\text{(9,107460)},\text{(9,107910)},\text{(9,1089)},\text{
   (9,108909)},\text{(9,109449)},\text{(9,10989)},\text{(9,109989)},\text
   {(9,110790)},\text{(9,9)}\}$

Comment: The family $(2,499999\dots 97)$ is a thing.

Comment: Almost any zero can be replaced by lots of zeros.